# Open containing directory in Windows Explorer from IntelliJ

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, windows-explorer

Is there a way (keyboard shortcut?) to open the folder of the currently opened file in Windows Explorer?

What I mean is this: When a java source file is open in IntelliJ, I'd like to open Windows Explorer on the folder containing that file. Is there a short way of doing that?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just padding out Peter Lawrey's answer, for Intellij 12.n on Windows 7 the steps for adding explorer as an external program would be:

1. File > Settings > External Tools
2. Click on the Plus (+) in the
3. Name: Open Containing Folder
4. Group: [select group]
5. Description: Open Containing Folder
6. Unselect "Open Console"
7. Program: explorer [or] C:\Windows\System32\explorer.exe
8. Parameters: $FileDir$
9. Working Directory: [leave blank]
10. Click OK

You can then add the External Tool as a keyed short cut through File > Settings > Keymap

Right clicking on a source file External Tools->Open Containing Folder is another way to use this tool.
[image]

Comment: For Windows10, Explorer is located at C:\windows\explorer.exe

Comment: Works great, just wanted to mention that the keymap settings option really is "External Tool", and then it lets you choose the open folder one in particular.

Answer (score 8):

As of version 2016.2 you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> while in the editor and navigate to different view. Choose "Show in file manager". You can even navigate to  a corresponding pom.xml from Maven view. Powerful, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of these plugins:

- "OpenContainingFolder"
- "Open containing folder in a File Explorer"

Comment: not that I really expected it, but they don't seem to exist anymore in 2023.

Comment: OpenContainingFolder exists but doesn't work on ubuntu (and an error on startup)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add to Simon B's answer that based on this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510) for selecting the file in addition to opening its parent folder in step 8 change "$FileDir$" to "/select, $FilePath$"

Answer (score 2):

[This help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-file-path.html) provides an easier way of doing this in later versions of IntelliJ as follows:-

1. Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then left-click the mouse on the tab containing the source code (i.e. the actual tab part at the top).
2. This will display a folder hierarchy with the filename at the top: To open the folder the file is in, click on the the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You can add explorer as an external program and add a hot key for that.
i.e. you will be able to select a directory or file and the same opens in windows explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Open In` contextual menu option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10: use "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" instead. (#7 Program:)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a keyboard shortcut via setting/keymap. See the image below. Select a folder/sub-folder from the project directory tree and key in the shortcut.

[image]